# ¿Cómo mostrar los errores de validación de un fieldset en el formulario en el que se encuentre y no en una vista aparte?

Tags: django-3.2.4, fieldset, validationerror

Tengo una clase `Carrito` que se relaciona con `Producto` a través de la clase `CarritoProducto` y el campo que indica dicha relación es `productos` que se encuentra en `Carrito`. Debido a ciertas especificidades, modifico el método `save_formset` de `CarritoAdmin` y en un fragmento de ese código, debo chequear si la cantidad que quiero adicionar de un producto a un carrito supera la cantidad total de ese producto que tengo en existencia y, de ser así, que el sistema muestre un error, pero no lo está mostrando en el fieldset de productos que se encuentra en el formulario de adicionar carrito, sino en una vista de Django que muestra; entre otras cosas, el error:

> ValidationError at /admin/app_name/carrito/add/ ['No hay tantos
> elementos disponibles de este producto.']

Las clases están definidas de esta forma:

**En models.py:**

```
class Producto(models.Model):
    ....
    cantidad = models.IntegerField(_('cantidad de este producto'))

class Carrito(models.Model):
    ....
    productos = models.ManyToManyField(Producto, through='CarritoProducto', verbose_name=_('productos'))

class CarritoProducto(models.Model):
    producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto,on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('producto'))
    carrito = models.ForeignKey(Carrito, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('carrito'))
    cantidad_productos = models.IntegerField(_('cantidad de producto'))
```

**En admin.py:**

```
class CarritoProductoInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = CarritoProducto
    extra = 1
    verbose_name = "Producto"
    verbose_name_plural="Productos"
    can_delete = True
    show_change_link = True

class CarritoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ....
    inlines = [CarritoProductoInline]

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        carrito=form.instance
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        for producto_carrito in instances:
            producto = producto_carrito.producto
            cantidad_productos = producto_carrito.cantidad_productos

            if CarritoProducto.objects.filter(carrito=carrito, producto=producto).exists():
                producto_carrito_instance = CarritoProducto.objects.get(carrito=carrito, producto=producto)
                total = producto.cantidad + producto_carrito_instance.cantidad_productos
                if total < cantidad_productos:
                    raise ValidationError(
                        _('No hay tantos elementos disponibles de este producto.'),
                    )
        ....
```

¿Cómo pudiera mostrar ese mismo error en el fieldset de productos que se encuentra en el formulario de `Carrito` que muestra Django en la administración?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Además de hacer algunas modificaciones necesarias en el método `save_formset` de `CarritoAdmin`, este es el código que utilizo:

En models.py en la clase `CarritoProducto`:

```
    def clean(self):
        try:
            producto = self.producto 
            carrito = self.carrito
            cantidad_productos = self.cantidad_productos    
        except:
            return
        if not cantidad_productos:
            return
        if CarritoProducto.objects.filter(carrito=carrito, producto=producto).exists():
            producto_carrito = CarritoProducto.objects.get(carrito=carrito, producto=producto)
            total = producto.cantidad + producto_carrito.cantidad_productos
            if total < cantidad_productos:
                raise ValidationError(
                    _('No hay tantos elementos disponibles de este producto.'),
                )
        else:
            total = producto.cantidad
            if total < cantidad_productos:
                raise ValidationError(
                    _('No hay tantos elementos disponibles de este producto.'),
                )
```